# Angular JS - Display validation errors when textfield lose focus

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to perform validation on input field , when user lefts the field .

**My.html**

```
   <div ng-form="form"  novalidate>
       <input type="email" name="userEmail" class="form-control username" 
ng-model="login.username" placeholder="Email" required />
     <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="login.password" required />
   <div class="invalid-message" ng-show="form.userEmail.$dirty && form.userEmail.$invalid">
    <span class="invalid-mail" ng-show="form.userEmail.$error.required">Invalid:Tell us
                            your email.</span> 
<span class="invalid-mail" ng-show="form.userEmail.$error.email">Invalid:This is not a valid email.</span>
     </div>
  </div>
```

I want to display invalid-message div and span , corresponding to error in email field . 
Now the code works fine .

But my requirement is to show invalid-message div and span when user finished typing in email.How to perform this your comments are welcome

Please find the fiddle here [Validation Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7YvH3/3/)

Comment: Can you add a jsFiddle for your example?

Comment: updated a fiddle @Abhi.

Comment: It's working fine i updated it . Please check @DavinTryon

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS Forms - Validate Fields After User Has Left Field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15798594/angularjs-forms-validate-fields-after-user-has-left-field)

Comment: @Circadian , I am displaying a div for validation message  , but that question adds a directive to check has-visited . But that's not fit into my requirement.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can accomplish this by setting a temporary variable that indicates whether the user has left the field.  Best place to do this is in the `ng-blur` directive (so, you can keep all of this on the view).

Here is an [updated fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/HH3qe/)

```
<form name="form"  novalidate>
    <input type="email" ng-blur="visitedEmail = true" name="userEmail" class="form-control username" ng-model="username" placeholder="Email" required />
    <input type="password" ng-blur="visitedPassword = true" name="password" class="form-control password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="password" required />
    <div ng-show="form.userEmail.$dirty && form.userEmail.$invalid && visitedEmail">
       <span ng-show="form.userEmail.$error.required">Invalid:Tell us  your email.</span> 
    <span  ng-show="form.userEmail.$error.email">Invalid:This is not a valid email.</span>
    </div>
</form>
```

You can see the introduction of `EmailVisited` that is set on `ng-blur`.

Answer (score 2):

try using form.userEmail.$touched