# Validate the input field on blur with Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I made a simple testing input fields, But I trying to convert the validation on blur, But i don't have any idea to achive this, since I am not such familiar with angularjs.

any one help me to validate only one blur in this example please..

myJs:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('FormController', function($scope) {
  $scope.fields = [
    {placeholder: 'Username', isRequired: true},
    {placeholder: 'Password', isRequired: true},
    {placeholder: 'Email (optional)', isRequired: false}
  ];

  $scope.submitForm = function() {
    alert("it works!");
  };
});
```

html:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
<form name="signup_form" ng-controller="FormController" ng-submit="submitForm()" novalidate>
  <div ng-repeat="field in fields" ng-form="signup_form_input">
    <input type="text"
           name="dynamic_input"
           ng-required="field.isRequired"
           ng-model="field.name"
           placeholder="{{field.placeholder}}" />
    <div ng-show="signup_form_input.dynamic_input.$dirty && signup_form_input.dynamic_input.$invalid">
      <span class="error" ng-show="signup_form_input.dynamic_input.$error.required">The field is required.</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" ng-disabled="signup_form.$invalid">Submit All</button>
</form>
</div>
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3gwebtrain/u5963/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can simply create a directive that has the same name as `ngModel`. Add a `blur` event on the element that changes the `$dirty` state of the `ngModel` to true. Make sure to change `ngModel`'s `$dirty` state to false when changes are made on the element by adding a callback inside `ngModel.$viewChangeListeners` array.

**[FORKED SAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ryeballar/ukbxxzse/1/)**

The directive looks something like this:

```
.directive('ngModel', function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elem, attr, ngModel) {
            elem.on('blur', function() {
                ngModel.$dirty = true;
                scope.$apply();
            });

            ngModel.$viewChangeListeners.push(function() {
                ngModel.$dirty = false;
            });

            scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
                elem.off('blur');
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Note: Don't worry if the custom directive name, `ngModel`, is the same with Angular's default `ngModel`, it will simply run both of them (it won't overwrite it). The `scope.$on('$destroy')` listener, removes the `blur` event handler when the scope is destroyed, e.g. when route changes and the controller is destroyed or when a field is removed which triggers a rebuild of the repeated DOM elements again(destroying the child scope created by `ng-repeat`).

Answer (score 22):

If you update to Angular 1.3 you can use `ng-model-options` to update the model on blur.

```
<input type="text"
       name="dynamic_input"
       ng-required="field.isRequired"
       ng-model="field.name"
       ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"
       placeholder="{{field.placeholder}}" />
```

<kbd>[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xbenjii/u5963/1/)</kbd>

However, if you can't update then there are plenty of ways to do this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15798594/angularjs-forms-validate-fields-after-user-has-left-field).

Answer (score 3):

```
            angular.module('myApp', [])
        .controller('FormController', function($scope) {
             $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#form input").on('blur', function(){
                    alert("Cannot be null");
                });
            });
          $scope.fields = [
            {placeholder: 'Username', isRequired: true},
            {placeholder: 'Password', isRequired: true},
            {placeholder: 'Email (optional)', isRequired: false}
          ];

          $scope.submitForm = function() {
            alert("it works!");
          };

        });
```

just give id to form and add the javascript code. Thats all. For live demo "http://jsfiddle.net/SaurabhGhewari/2ko9bamk/"

Comment: DOM Manipulation inside a Controller is really frowned upon, as it is hard to test and breaks the separation of concerns between Business Logic and Presentation

Comment: Thanks for info. Please provide other way for this so i can also change in my project.

Comment: I posted an answer not a while ago actually.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a custom validation, a simple way to go is using ngBlur. Add the following to your field and write a validation function in your controller:

```
<input type="text"
       ng-model="fieldVal" 
       ng-blur="validate(fieldVal)"/>
```

You can also use ng-model-options combined with ng-change

```
<input type="text" 
       ng-modle="fildsVal" 
       ng-model-option="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" 
       ng-change="validate(fieldVal)" />
```

I also found the debounce option very nice to trigger the validation. You can time it so that when user is done typing, the validation triggers:

```
<input type="text"
       ng-model-options="{ debounce: 800 }" 
       ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{1,9}$/" />
```