# Angular: Ng-show only while off Input Field in Form

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

https://jsfiddle.net/jzhang172/xu93yubL/

The particular issue is in my **E-mail input field**.
Is it possible to only display the ng-show message **after** the field is validated and when the user is not inside the input field?

In other words, I want the ng-show message to disappear if the user is on the input field.

I've tried a number of combinations of logic and haven't been able to get it to work:

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('formExample', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.master = {};

    $scope.update = function(user) {
      $scope.master = angular.copy(user);
    };

    $scope.reset = function(form) {
      if (form) {
        form.$setPristine();
        form.$setUntouched();
      }
      $scope.user = angular.copy($scope.master);
    };

    $scope.reset();
  }]);
})(window.angular);
```

```html
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>


<body ng-app="formExample">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <form name="form" class="css-form" novalidate>
    Name:
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.name" name="uName" required="" />
    <br />
    <div ng-show="form.$submitted || form.uName.$touched">
      <div ng-show="form.uName.$error.required">Tell us your name.</div>
    </div>

    E-mail:
    <input type="email" ng-model="user.email" name="uEmail" required="" />
    <br />
    <div ng-show="form.$submitted || form.uEmail.$touched">
      <span ng-show="form.uEmail.$error.required" style="background:red;">Tell us your email.</span>
      <span ng-show="form.uEmail.$error.email"style="background:red;">This is not a valid email.</span>
    </div>


  </form>

</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS Forms - Validate Fields After User Has Left Field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15798594/angularjs-forms-validate-fields-after-user-has-left-field)

Comment: I tried those solutions unfortunately and I wasn't able to get the desired results, maybe I missed something though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **ngFocus** and **ngBlur** directives to achieve desired result...

Just set some variable false on ngFocus and set true with ngBlur and add that variable into your ngShow condition...

```
 <input type="email" ng-model="user.email" name="uEmail" required="" ng-focus="showEmailValidationMsg = false;" ng-blur="showEmailValidationMsg = true;"/>
    <br />
    <div ng-show="(form.$submitted || form.uEmail.$touched) && showEmailValidationMsg">
      <span ng-show="form.uEmail.$error.required" style="background:red;">Tell us your email.</span>
      <span ng-show="form.uEmail.$error.email"style="background:red;">This is not a valid email.</span>
    </div>
```

and here is working [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/usqk1ypk/)...